# Is there a better way to write this? Deleting file from multiple folders

Tags: windows, batch

Is there a better way to write this? Deleting file from multiple folders.

```
if exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op" (cd C:\Program Files\Max\Op
del Lud.ini 
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op\Lud.ini" echo "Lud.ini was removed")

if exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op001" (cd C:\Program Files\Max\Op001
del Lud.ini 
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op001\Lud.ini" echo "Lud.ini was removed")

if exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op002" (cd C:\Program Files\Max\Op002
del Lud.ini 
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op002\Lud.ini" echo "Lud.ini was removed")

if exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op003" (cd C:\Program Files\Max\Op003
del Lud.ini 
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op003\Lud.ini" echo "Lud.ini was removed")

if exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op004" (cd C:\Program Files\Max\Op004
del Lud.ini 
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Max\Op004\Lud.ini" echo "Lud.ini was removed
```

Comment: You understand that, even if you don't delete the folder, your batch script is going to indicate you deleted the folder.  I doubt that is what you want to happen.  *I am just speaking of your script regardless of any syntax error you might or might not have.*

Comment: Powershell...Powershell is a better way to write this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per sample you have provided; you are deleting `LUD.ini` files from all sub-folders of `C:\Program Files\Max` folder. Following batch file should work for this case. However, you may want to modify it to implement additional logging or checks.

Following batch file will uses `forfiles` command to look into `C:\Program Files\Max` folder and all sub-folder for file named `Lud.ini`. If file is found, it is deleted. If you want to print full path of file, use `@path` with `echo` at end.

```
@ECHO OFF
FORFILES /P "C:\Program Files\Max" /S /M Lud.ini /C "CMD /C ECHO Y | DEL @PATH & ECHO Lud.ini was removed"
```

Comment: Thought you need batch file to add additional functionality and checks. If you just want to delete all files named `LUD.ini`, it can be done by using simple DEL command. Use `DEL /F /S LUD.ini` command. You need to run this command from `C:\Program Files\Max` folder.